# Laravel elixir compile multiple less files

Tags: laravel, laravel-elixir

I have this two files in `resources/assets/less` folder `style.less` and `admin/style.less`. I want to compile this files to diffrent paths as the following:

`style.less` compiled to `public/css/`

and the other one compiled to `public/admin/styles/`

this is What i did in the gulpfile.js

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.less('style.less', 'public/css/');
    mix.less('admin/style.less', 'public/admin/styles/');
});
```

but this compile only one file.
What is the problem and how can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have a project that compiles two different less files to two different css files.
The only difference that I see is that I specify the full destination path including the file name.

So, for your case, it will be:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.less('style.less', 'public/css/style.css')
       .less('admin/style.less', 'public/admin/styles/style.css');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not got the answer for this yet. But have tried some alternatives, thought will share.

I was thinking we can do like below

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.less('style.less', 'public/css/')
       .less('admin/style.less', 'public/admin/styles/');
});
```

But according to the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/elixir#usage) we can't make multiple call to sass or less method. So it is only compiling the latest less file (which in this case admin/style.css).

We can do like this

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.less(['style.less', 'admin/style2.less'], 'public/css/');
});
```

but this will compile both into the same folder.

Hoping to know, how can we do it to different folders.

I tried copying the second file into a separate folder, but that also doesn't work

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.less(['style.less', 'admin/style2.less'], 'public/css/')
       .copy('public/css/style2.css', 'public/admin/style.css');
});
```

Probably this is because each requests are async and when the copy is getting called, that time the style2.css is not ready yet.

Comment: Are you sure it will work? As far as I know for sass it doesn't

Comment: Sorry Marcin, It doesn't. Looks like we can only use one instance of less or sass function according to the documentation. I take back my answer. I assumed it will. Sorry!

Comment: for less/sass you can import one less/sass in to another. but it works for a single file format obviously.

Answer (score 0):

```
mix.less('resources/assets/less/app.scss', 'public/css').
    less('resources/assets/less/admin/style.less', 'public/admin/styles');
```